# google enterprise license manager api - Unauthorized operation for the given domain

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-api-client, google-license-manager

The LicenseAssignments.get api returns 200 OK

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/sku/Google-Apps-For-Business/user/<email>
```

Response:

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
    "kind": "licensing#licenseAssignment",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/sku/Google-Apps-For-Business/user/<email>",
    "userId": "<email>",
    "productId": "Google-Apps",
    "skuId": "Google-Apps-For-Business"
}
```

However LicenseAssignments.listForProduct returns "403 Forbidden"

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/users?customerId=my_customer
```

Response:

```
403 Forbidden

- Show headers -

{
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Unauthorized operation for the given domain."
    }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Unauthorized operation for the given domain."
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get 403 forbidden for the second request?

Comment: are you able to reproduce this behavior in the API Explorer? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/listForProduct. Are both the customerID and productId set?

Comment: This was resolved when I used my domain name as 'customerId'. It's different from behavior of other APIs where customerId is 'my_customer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved when I used 'domain name' (e.g. something.com) as 'customerId'. This is different from the usual behavior of other Google APIs where 'customerId' is 'my_customer'.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/users?customerId=<domain name>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say, six years later, this was really helpful. Thank you!