# how to check the license level using the Google API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to use the Google api to get the license status of an user

And the api url is
https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/Google-Apps/sku/1010020027/user/<user_id>?customerId=<customer_id>

But getting the error as
"Error: Unauthorized operation for the given domain"

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998293/google-enterprise-license-manager-api-unauthorized-operation-for-the-given-dom

Comment: Thank you Jason ! But had already tried the suggestion in that thread. still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

are other license-related calls working?

aside from enabling the api, did you also go to admin.google.com > security > api controls > domain wide delegation and associate required scopes with your client?

in case a clue here is helpful -- some example code i used to get product license count, which also works per user:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/1214

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.